# Failing to repair an external HFS volume

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, filesystems, data-recovery, fsck

Trying to repair an external hard drive (Seagate portable 2TB), it had one partition that contained both time machine stuff and some files that i only have one copy of unfortunately.
I assume that what happend is either it was disconnected inappropriately while doing some time machine routine, or it had a power problem while connecting via hub to MacBook Pro 2016 (had to use a hub to convert usb2 to usbc).

I've been doing research through the web for quite a time now trying to access my files and make sure everything is backed up before im formatting anything, but it seems to be inaccessible to browse, read or copy from.

I've tried:

1. Reboot, reconnect, change hub, change cable, change connecting port, change computer (other mac, don't have a pc to check it on yet).
2. Activate FirstAid via Disk Utilities, reboot in safe mode, repeat the same.

When using firstAid i receive the following:

```
Running First Aid on “DH Backup” (disk2s1)

Repairing file system.
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_hfs -fy -x /dev/rdisk2s1
File system check exit code is 8.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
File system verify or repair failed. : (-69845)

Operation failed…
```

3. next thing i've tried is using fsck_hfs with different flags:

`sudo fsck_hfs -drfy /dev/disk2s1`
which returned:

```
journal_replay(/dev/disk2s1) returned 0
** /dev/rdisk2s1
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=32768 cacheSize=1048576K.
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-522.0.9).
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
   The volume name is DH Backup
** Checking extents overflow file.
** Checking catalog file.
** Rebuilding catalog B-tree.
hfs_UNswap_BTNode: invalid node height (1)

** Rechecking volume.
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
   The volume name is DH Backup
** Checking extents overflow file.
** Checking catalog file.
** Checking multi-linked files.
** Checking catalog hierarchy.
** Checking extended attributes file.
** Checking multi-linked directories.
    privdir_valence=17384, calc_dirlinks=58400, calc_dirinode=17385
   Invalid parent for directory inode (id = 4968950)
   (It should be 19 instead of 18)
   Invalid name for directory inode (id = 4968950)
   (It should be dir_4968950 instead of temp4968950)
   Incorrect number of directory hard links
    Error getting link=4983759 for inode=4968950
** The volume DH Backup could not be verified completely.
    volume check failed with error 7
    volume type is pure HFS+
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00
    primary VHB is at block 2 0x02
    alternate VHB is at block 3907024063 0xe8e074bf
    sector size = 512 0x200
    VolumeObject flags = 0x07
    total sectors for volume = 3907024065 0xe8e074c1
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00
    CheckHFS returned -1317, fsmodified = 1
```

and the `fsck_hfs -yprd` which returned more or less the same output.

I'm adding here the `diskutil info` output also, just in case it helps in anyway:

```
   Device Identifier:         disk2s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk2

   Volume Name:               DH Backup
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            Apple_HFS
   File System Personality:   Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):             hfs
   Name (User Visible):       Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                   Unknown (not mounted)
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               9F04F085-82D2-3DD6-8F44-AB584B60CFFB
   Partition Offset:          32768 Bytes (64 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 2.0 TB (2000396321280 Bytes) (exactly 3907024065 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:         0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Info not available
```

I know there are some softwares around like DiskWarrior etc. but they are quite expensive for me plus they guarantee nothing preliminary to the purchase, and so - **If you have anything for me, maybe regarding to fixing the iNode stuff i would be extremely thankful**.
As i mentioned before, the data in important for me and i'd like to try and access it before i reformat.

Thanks again!

Comment: This is one of those tasks I would immediately give to Disk Warrior. There's very little else of any use whatsoever in these circumstances.

Comment: Normally I don't but: seconded! Apple's disk repair tools are basic, at best. This is an HFS+ disk (DW fixes those) and if the data is worth that much to you then get Diskwarrior. It will *most likely* fix the problem. Trying to do it manually is an exercise in frustration, unless you want to send it out to a disk *recovery* company and have them charge you hundreds for that.

Comment: Guess i'll give it a try and update.

Comment: Do you have an update? I've got a very similar problem and think about DiskWarrior